Login As Customer banner not showing when custom module is open
When we use Login as Customer for any customer from the admin panel it will redirect to frontend able to view all the pages for the particular customer and it is working.
But the banner is not showing when navigating to any custom module as shown in the below picture.

When I debug the js file the customer is not loading. For this, I also added cacheable="false" for my layout block, but still the customer name not updating. We can see it's showing Magento, but the actual customer's name is CED-Smith.
Any help?

Found myself.
For a customized full-width layout, I'm using the below code to remove content. Now, I just removed the main.content in the layout by using the below code.
<referenceContainer name="main.content" remove="true"/>
This line causes to load the required information for the Magento website.
After removing this line, working fine.
